# Reuse outgoing webbook with multiple Teams/Groups?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created an outgoing webhook in my Team and I want to use the same webhook for other Teams/Groups

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is basically what Connectors are for. Have a look at [What are webhooks and connectors?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors) to see more.

It requires you to build a Teams "app" (i.e. building a manifest and deploying to the internal Teams store) but should cover what you need.

Comment: how can I use my connector id in webhook? pls explain me about it more. I have registred my connector on Connectors Developer Dashboard and I got the connector Id and I have added it into my cutsom app manifest.json file. but my question is how can i use it in my outgoing webhook?

Comment: So this kind of "replaces" the outgoing webhook in a way - instead of using a one-off webhook, you install the connector as an app to the Channel. The end result should basically be the same, but the "idea" of the webhook now becomes re-usable, at least as I understand it.

Comment: If I used connector manifest and uploaded a app and installed a connector in one of the channel how can i get the details or name of that channel or group where my connector is added?

Comment: So the one key difference between a webhook and a connector (aside from the fact that it can be re-used) is that there's a "configuration" experience (a popup) that's part of the setup by the user of a connector. In there you can set it to pass the channel name as a querystring parameter to your connector, for example.

Comment: Is there any such java sample code that I can refer to achieve this?

Comment: Well you can code your connector in any language you want - it just needs to receive a POST request. Did you see this page maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating